# Dynamically change a cell's backgroundView.backgroundColor

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicolor

I have the following code to create a cell's background view as a rounded rectangle:

```
- (UIView *)createBackgroundView
{
    CGRect background = CGRectMake(50, 25, self.frame.size.width - 60, 90);
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:background];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78 green:0.96 blue:0.39 alpha:1];
    [backgroundView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
    [backgroundView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    return backgroundView;
}
```

Later on in the program I want to update the backgroundView's backgroundColor, I've tried

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

in both cellForRowAtIndexPath and willDisplayCell and neither seems to update it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have to go about it is:

```
[cell setBackgroundView:[self createBackgroundView]];
```

---

Probably you should also add an argument to the method:

```
- (UIView *)createBackgroundView:(UIColor *)color;
```